# Incoming UDP packets get queued then lumped together using Python

Tags: python, performance, udp

I am sending packets across a wireless network using UDP and Android, and receiving with Python. I'm sending rather time sensitive data, and I have a issue where the packets aren't being read fast enough / correctly. Basically, to gauge the actual problem, I measure the time between consecutive packets. Below is such a series of packets, where they are sent from the other application once every 20 milliseconds.

As you can see, around packet 19 things start to get messy. There is a delay of 50 ms, then the next consecutive packets are read immediately, as if they have already arrived. Packet 40 is a good demonstration of how bad it actually gets. 110 ms since the last packet, then 4 packets within 2 ms.

**I have verified with Wireshark that the packets are actually sent regularly** (so the problem doesn't seem to be with the other application)

**My questions are these, answer the most appropriate one:**

1. What can I do to resolve the problem, or what further steps should I take to analyze it?
2. Are there socket options available that could help me?
3. Am I doing Python UDP wrong?

Directly below is a simple chart describing the packet flow. Below that is the python code I use to read UDP packets.

```
N   (ms)
1    21
2    21
3    19
4    21
5    20
6    19
7    20
8    19
9    20
10   18
11   21
12   20
13   21
14   20
15   19
16   20
17   25
18   18
19   50
20   0.23
21   08
22   29
23   09
24   21
25   26
26   18
27   83
28   0.21
29   0.35
30   0.75
31   23
32   70
33   1.21
34   0.23
35   0.21
36   20
37   22
38   11
39   20
40   110
41   0.69
42   0.42
43   0.44
44   0.39
45   13
```

Here is the net code. `self.callback` puts the message into a python queue, and another thread reads from it. I am using `CPython 3.3`. The problem persists on at least 2 more computers (The same symptoms, I haven't verified with Wireshark or measuring the time)

```
self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

def start(self):
    while 1:
        try:
            received_data, address = self.socket.recvfrom(576)
            received_time = time.perf_counter()

            if self.is_correct_protocol(received_data):
                seq_id = struct.unpack(">H", received_data[4:6])[0]

                if self.test_already_acknowledged(address, seq_id):
                    if not self.check_and_handle_ping_request(address, unpack(received_data), received_time):                            
                        self.callback(address, received_time, unpack(received_data))
```

Comment: Wow.  This is a good question.  I'd wish all POs would be that elaborate.

Comment: I guess what you measure is just a symptom of Unix/Linux/Android not being a real-time-system.  UDP packets have not guaranteed timeframe in which they are suppoed to be delivered.  It's just "as fast as possible", so the OS is free to do other "important" things in between which might sometimes hinder the delivery.  UDP packets even can overtake each other (I'm surprised you haven't experienced this as well).  I'm pretty sure this is not a Python issue.

Comment: @alfe thanks, I try to provide all I can... And thanks for the reply. I'm not so sure of your diagnosis though - io such as udp typically use completion ports and should achieve very fast speeds.. especially since wireshark can successfully intercept the packages. 110 milliseconds is a very long time. Notice that most udp packets arrive very accurately, most within 2 ms.

Comment: Yeah, they do most of the time.  But especially if there are may hops on your route or if more than one route can be chosen (due to load shifts for instance), UDP is not reliably ordered or in time.  I guess in your case you have no intermediate hops or similar, so you might be able to achieve an appearing great accuracy in these values *most* of the time.  But I propose not to rely on that.  Maybe choosing a different protocol (bluetooth for instance) would be a safer way.